# Clustering for variables with large amount of categories

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataset which, has variables with a lot of categories (some more than 1000). Since, large amount of categories effect the accuracy of the model. I saw some literature stating that if you do not have domain knowledge to group categories that have less than 5% of representation in the dataset.

My idea is that would it be possible to cluster these variables and will it make any sense to do so. For example if there are many variables which have a lot of categories it would be an issue to cluster one variable since as mentioned above the accuracy would be less because of the high number of categories in other variables.

Please let me know is this method valid.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking for. Could you give us more details?

Comment: Ok. Simply, if we want to reduce the number of categories (excluding target variable) in a variable in a dataset, could we use clustering to do it and does it make sense when there are many variables with lot of categories. See this link for the understanding of the question and other methods used. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/easy-methods-deal-categorical-variables-predictive-modeling/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have done the EDA well, you can try the categorical_encoder categorization  if you haven't tried it yet.We cannot use the famous one hot encoder algo here,that's for sure. It will create as many number of columns as there were before. Which would be unnecessary. You may try the backward difference encoding.
[Check this beauty](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/categorical-data)